# Why doesnt my arraylist print its valuse?

Tags: java

I have been trying to  create a metho that reads from a textfile which has 3 records(name,age)

In my class i include getters setters compareTo and toString methods.

Mark Doug, 21

David Brough , 19

Mark Eden , 17

The error i'm getting is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: " 28"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:569)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    at lab7.People.readPersons(People.java:44)
    at lab7.People.main(People.java:63)
```

The method must split the name with age (which is already done)
and print the arraylist

```
    public static List<People> readPersons(String fileName)    throws FileNotFoundException{
        Scanner sc= new Scanner(new File(fileName));
        List <People> persons= new ArrayList<>();
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            String line = sc.nextLine();
            String[] alo = line.split(",");
            int age = Integer.parseInt(alo[1]);
            String name = alo[0];
            persons.add(new People(name, age));
        }
        return persons;


        }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name " +getName()+"age " +getAge();
    }




    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        System.out.println(readPersons("C:\\Users\\Mark \\Desktop\\CS\\JAVA\\exersice\\src\\Person\\data"));
```

I copied the directory from the 'data.txt' file (which is in the same package with my Person class
Unfortunately, I'm getting an error which I don't know why.

Comment: Can you paste the error you got while doing so?

Comment: @SidharthaShankar done

Comment: The error message is very specific and even includes the invalid input.

Comment: @Arnaud Did you see anywhere in my code asking for help about splitting?

Comment: @JohnMichael : Did you read the linked question ? Your problem is the remaining spaces in the tokens after the split :  `" 28"` is not a valid string to parse to a number , `"28"` is.

Answer (score 0):

Trim your number like this before converting to int:

```
int age = Integer.parseInt(alo[1].trim());
```

Because that extra space on " 28" is causing the number format Exception.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to trim the age value to avoid the Number Format Exception.

Java8 lets you do it in 1 line:

```
String[] alo = Arrays.stream(line.split(",")).map(String::trim).toArray(String[]::new);
```

And then you can fetch the name and age as you are doing in your code.